# Evaluating $ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\log x}{x^2} $

Tags: limits

How to find the following limit?

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\log x}{x^2} $$

I've tried to use *L'Hopital's rule*, but it's not applicable here, then what is the step I can follow to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a substitution $t = \frac{1}{x}$. Then your limit becomes

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} t^2(1 + \log(t))$$

And it's clear that both terms goes to positive infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply simple limit rules

$$\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}= \underbrace{\frac 1{x^2}}_{\stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}+\infty}\cdot \underbrace{(1-\log x)}_{\stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}+\infty}\stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$$